# Fault Tolarent Web Role Initialization in Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have a WebRole that runs a WCF service. This role accesses storage, queue, and tables. Therefore, I have connection strings and some other settings kept in configuration files (names, timetolive etc).

Assuming that config files can change during runtime, I want to be able to reinitialize these settings. Let's say I have my WebRole read config values while starting:

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
  public override bool OnStart()
  {
    string connString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
  }
}
```

I have a WCF service called `MyService`:

```
public MyService()
{
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
  CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
}
```

I initialize the storage client inside a default constructor. How can I pass that setting read by the role to the service? This way I can make anybody initiate my service with specific settings and have a good test coverage.

NOTE: Passing settings as parameters does not sound like an option (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279189/explicitly-calling-a-service-constructor-when-hosting-a-wcf-web-service-on-iis)).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you move the Azure code to another class and reference to it through interface something like this

```
public interface IStorageCreator{
        CloudQueueClient GetQueueClient();

    }


    public class AzureStorageCreator:IAzureStorageCreator{
       public CloudQueueClient GetQueueClient(){
            string connString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
            CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

           return queueClient;
       }
    }
```

And then add your dependency to WCF service through injection, By doing that way you can test your service and fake it as you like.

Cheers.